# {"error":"no handler found for uri [/blog/article/1] and method [PUT]"} elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, php-curl

I am trying to add data to elasticsearch with both PUT and POST

```
curl -k -XPUT 'https://localhost:9200/blog/article/1' -d '{"title": "New version of Elasticsearch released!", "content": "Version 2.2 released today!", "priority": 10, "tags": ["announce", "elasticsearch", "release"] }'
```

but I am getting error:

```json
{"error":"no handler found for uri [/blog/article/1] and method [PUT]"}
```

```
curl -k -XPOST 'https://localhost:9200/blog/article/' -d '{"title": "New version of Elasticsearch released!", "content": "Version 2.2 released today!", "priority": 10, "tags": ["announce", "elasticsearch", "release"] }'
```

```json
{"error":"no handler found for uri [/blog/article/] and method [POST]"}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Tldr;

This is expected behaviour as those endpoint do not exist.
You should refer to [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) for indexing documents.

## Solution

Request to index a document should look like so:

> PUT /<target>/_doc/<_id>
>
> POST /<target>/_doc/
>
> PUT /<target>/_create/<_id>
>
> POST /<target>/_create/<_id>

In my example I choose the first flavour.

Noticed I have renamed the index to `blog_article`

```
curl -k -XPOST 'https://localhost:9200/blog_article/_doc/1' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title": "New version of Elasticsearch released!", "content": "Version 2.2 released today!", "priority": 10, "tags": ["announce", "elasticsearch", "release"] }'
```

Comment: But now I am getting this {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}

Comment: Ah because you need the header `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`, I forgot about it

Comment: error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/blog_article/_doc/1]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/blog_article/_doc/1]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
this time above error is coming

Comment: You need to authenticate yourself

Comment: I am new to elasticsearch can you please help me with command like where to put authentication value also I have tried to index this way according to curl -u ank:password https://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -k 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "title": "One", "tags": ["ruby"]
}' as suggested here elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/… but it also gives the same error as above

Comment: That is a different question @AnkitRaj. We need more information about your set up. what password did you set ? which user has been created ? are you using `xpack` ? Ask another question

Comment: Try again without "-u" flag, because you already informed the user inside the url.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error `No handler found for uri [/indexname/Â ] and method [DELETE]`, which was caused by left over undesired white space. If you are using Linux, check with VI whether there is any left-over white space by moving the cursor to the end of the call to `curl`.